# moving a symfony2 project to another PC

Tags: symfony

I developed a project using symfony2/PHP and now I am willing to shift this project to another machine how can I do the same

I tried following
1)I copied project folder to www folder of another machine
2)I edited app\config\parameters.yml on another system
but is not working its giving different erros

Can any one tell me exact staeps

Comment: The error should show you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the source and the database should be enough. It is possible, you may have to clean cache.

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

- Try clearing cache; open console / terminal and type **php app/console cache:clear**
- Try chmod / chown or if you are on a windows machine, try change the owner, check permissions
- Try re-run: **php composer.phar update**
- Check your php-version and extensions. (See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html)

Comment: Hi it seems I am getting folder permission issue, although I added full permission to every user o project folder but still getting following error

Comment: file_get_contents(C:\wamp\www\Symfony\src\Woms\AdminBundle/Resources/views/Default/home.html.twig): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Woms-Symfony\Symfony\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php line 126

Comment: Are you sure you have permission on that folder and the files??? And are you sure that home.html.twig is really exists?

Comment: Hi Thanks, problem solved the issue is with folder name i moved my project  to www\symfony and error get solved

Comment: So, is my question helped you? If so, please accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the cache worked for me.

type php app/console cache:clear